# Database data inconsistency

Tags: mysql

I have three tables on my database the `BILL,RECHARGE AND SENT`.The `BILL` table has a column named `UNITBALS` and the `RECHARGE` table has a column named `UNITS` also the `SENT` table has a column named `VOLUME`.What normally should happen is that when a customer recharge his account his new `UNITS` will be sum with his old `UNITS` on the `RECHARGE` table and the sum of the `VOLUME` of the total sent message on the `SENT` table will be subtracted from the sum of the `UNITS` on `RECHARGE` table and the result will be used to update the `UNITBALS` on the `BILL` table.But the problem now is that when customer recharge their account the `UNITBALS` on the BILL table is updated with the new balance or sometimes the `UNITBALS` is being updated with higher values than it ought to be.There is a kind of inconsistency in my database now and the customers are complaining.

Comment: I think we're going to need to know more to answer this.  Can you provide the DML that's being used to make these updates?

Answer (score 1):

So from what I gather you are storing the results of a aggregate calculation on BILL.UNITBALS

Specifically

`BILL.UNITBALS = SUM(RECHARGE.UNITS) - SUM(SENT.VOLUME)`

Unless you made a serious error, what's likely going on is due to a pending transaction and the [transaction isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) you're missing a value that you should be taken into account.

Because of this issue I try and do whatever I can to avoid storing the results of a calculation in the DB

Typically this means that I do the calculation every time I retrieve the data. This may (or may not be) a performance issue but at least you get more opportunities to get the correct information.

If the perf penalty is too high then I recommend that you do a reconcilation only once every 24 hours and add a disclaimer like "payments made will not appear on your account for X business days"